# NSURLConnection crashing the app

Tags: swift

I am downloading Json data from server using NSURLConnection class. I parse the data in background thread, however in `connection() delegate method the app is crashing`. Below is the screenshot. The code is also available in the image below. Why is this happening?

Regards

[image]

**UPDATE:**

With breakpoints removed:

[image]

Comment: I can only see your program stopped on a breakpoint -- no crash is evident from the image...

Comment: I tried with removing all break points but the app still froze

Comment: Did it crash or freeze?

Comment: well it froze. I though it was crashing, but it is not. I am a newbie dev

Comment: then, remove the breakpoints, let the program crash and post the relevant console messages, please...

Comment: As I can see the existing console message, if this is the server `JSON` response that you printed, it is `not a valid JSON response`, i suppose the server has some error and the error details are coming as a response which is `not getting parse` and `program crashes`, possibly.

Comment: @NeverHopeless That is not the case because I tried with iTunes json data from apple website still the same behavior.

Comment: @sergio I have removed the breakpoints, see the updated questoin

Comment: Please, paste the backtrace. If you don't know how to, type `bt` and hit return inside the xcode console and copy the relevant output.

Comment: You might find this helpful: http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Comment: ok so the crash problem is fixed now but it is giving me EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION error at NSJSONSerialzation.JsonObjectWithData().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to use `UIAlertView` and that is causing a crash. Now, from your code is not clear how you are doing that. In any case `UIAlertView` is deprecated under iOS 8 and this might explain the issue when using Swift (although using deprecated methods or classes does not usually causes a crash in Obj-C).

You could try with a `UIAlertController` and set its `preferredStyle` to `UIAlertControllerStyleAlert`:

```
var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I didn't know this but the problem got fixed when I remove AlertView. I thought the error occured because of running UI stuff on in ConnectionDidFinish() which I think is running on background thread by default. However, the problem lies in NSJSonSerialization which is causing EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION for the NSMUtableData. I have double checked, NSMUtableData is not empty. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You can check on which thread the delegate method runs by calling `[NSThread isMainThread]`. Apart from this I don't understand, maybe: you removed the alert, the crash went away; so you have another crash? would you mind posting the details? anyway, if it is another crash, you should possibly ask it in a different question, otherwise we will address all of your crashes here and it is not very convenient... :-)

Comment: I found out that passing data to the protocol method causes EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION. Now when I put inside `connectionDidFinishLoading()` if NSThread.isMainThread(), it gives this error

Comment: Any suggestions about what can be causing this? The reason I am not creating a new question because I didn't know the cause at first for the problem, now that I know and as it is related to this question, I think it should be solved here :)

Comment: BTW +1 for the great suggestions so far :)

Comment: the problem is: from your previous comment it is not clear which error you are getting now... apart from this, if `NSJSonSerialization` is causing the crash I would at least need to see the statement where it crashes and the exact crash log... please, edit your question with the relevant information (as much as you can)...

Comment: When the alertview pops up, the screen behind it gets black. It shouldn't be happening. Why is that?

Comment: no idea, but have you tried using the new `UIAlertController`?

Comment: yep I am using `UIAlertController`. UIAlertView is not supported on iOS 8.